# Converter data javascript para trabalho no PHP

Tags: php, javascript, datetime

Estou tentando capturar a data do arquivo via javascript e mandar para o PHP.

Motivo?

Quero a data da ultima alteração do arquivo.

```
$('#last_modified').val(arquivo[0].lastModified);
```

Variavel arquivo é:

```
<input type="file" name="teste" onchange="pegaArquivo(this.files)">
```

O que me retorna "1423493594000" para a data: Mon Feb 09 2015 12:53:14 GMT-0200 (BRST)

Porém, quando o PHP lê esta data ele sempre retorna a mesma: 31/12/1969

No php eu faço:

```
echo date ("d/m/Y", filectime($_POST['last_modified']));
```

Poderiam me ajudar?

Comment: O JavaScript trabalha em milisegundos e o PHP em segundos, 1423493594000 em javascript dá feb 2015, em php dá lá para 2028 se não dividires por `1000`... como estás a passar para o PHP?

Comment: Exatamente como o @Sergio disse.
Este tópico é um pouco parecido com a sua dúvida, dê uma olhada e vê se te ajuda: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10837022/convert-php-date-into-javascript-date-format

Comment: Desculpe-me, atualizei o post:
echo date ("d/m/Y", filectime($_POST['last_modified']));

Comment: Raul, de uma olhada em: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/ logo no começo ele aplica exatamente o que você gostaria. Mostrar a data de modificação. Neste setor **Using form input for selecting**. Faça um teste, faça um upload e veja o resultado :)

Comment: Obrigado @Sergio, era isso mesmo, dividir por 1000.

Comment: Obrigado @RenilsonAndrade, ajudou bastante também. =)

Comment: @RafaelWithoeft vou ler com calma o link, talvez me ajude mais ainda =) A proposito, como se pronuncia seu sobrenome?

Comment: @Raul3k **" Vítef "**; Acredito ser de origem Alemã... kkkkk

Comment: @Raul3k eu ainda não ví no teu código onde estava o erro, nõ colocaste de onde vem `arquivo[0].lastModified`. Mas se encontraste a solução podes apagar a pergunta ou colocar uma resposta.

Comment: @RafaelWithoeft Imagino você soletrando por telefone rs
Acabei de postar a solução juntamente com o código =)

Comment: Obs:
    onchange="pegaArquivo(this.files)"
Olha o onchange, é aqui que estou pegando =)

Comment: @Raul3k Sim, sempre é uma dificuldade, nem tento mais falar, já começo soletrando. kkkkk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O meu erro era tentar converter o time passado pelo javascript direto para o PHP.

Após os comentários na propria pergunta,fiz as alterações solicitadas e agora está funcionando.

Segue o código funcionando para quem quiser ver:

```
<script>
    function pegaArquivo(arquivoSelecionado) {
        if(arquivoSelecionado[0]){
            $('#last_modified').val(arquivoSelecionado[0].lastModified);
        }
    }
</script>

<input type="hidden" id="last_modified" name="last_modified" />
<input type="file" name="teste" onchange="pegaArquivo(this.files)"> <input type="submit">
```

No PHP:

```
echo 'Data do arquivo: <br>';
$dateInfo = getdate($_POST['last_modified']);
echo date ("d/m/Y", (int) $dateInfo[0]/1000);
```

O truque foi dividir o time do javascript por 1000 já que o Javascript trabalha com milisegundos e o PHP com segundos.

Obrigado a todos.